# trim specific parts of a string and put it in a table

Tags: php, wordpress

I have managed to get data from table in the data base, something like this:

```
$s = explode("»;}i:1;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:7;",$data);
a:7:{i:0;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:6;s:10: »user_value »;s:4: »jack »;}i:1;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:7;s:10: »user_value »;s:5: »david »;}i:2;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:8;s:10: »user_value »;s:5: »45587″;}i:3;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:9;s:10: »user_value »;s:3: »447″;}i:4;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:10;s:10: »user_value »;s:3: »115″;}i:5;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:11;s:10: »user_value »;s:6: »Agadir »;}i:6;a:2:{s:8: »field_id »;i:13;s:10: »user_value »;s:0: » »;}}
```

I want to trim this and send it to a table  to be like

```
jack // david // 45587 // 477 // 115 // agadir
```

Comment: Seems like that is a serialized data , Use `unserialize()` instead of `explode()`

Comment: sorry, maybe i didn't things. the things is  am using  ninja forms plugin with Wordpress. i am trying to display the records on a page using a table. here is the coonection codes : [insert_php]
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM vl21i_ninja_forms_subs"); 

echo "ID"."  "."Name"."  "."Last name"."<br><br>";
foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo $row->id."  ".$row->data."<br>";
 }
[/insert_php]

Comment: Can you post the value of `$data` ?

Comment: you mean post it here?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran sorry making it hard for you to help. here is how it looks like: [link](http://lahbib.x27.us/liste/)

Comment: In general it is not recommended to use string manipulation functions if you want to deal with serialized data. Use the handy Wordpress function `maybe_unserialize()`, place every variable in array and loop and extract what you need.